# If conditions based on number of inputs fields filled

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, advanced-search

I am currently attempting to do an Advanced Search function. Currently, I have a form with 7 possible input fields. What I am trying to achieve is that as users fill in the form fields, these fields will determine the conditions set for my backend to "filter" out the data.

Hence, if a user fields in 2 fields out of the 7, these 2 inputs fields will be used as my backend's filter conditions. If another users fills in 3 input fields out of the 7, then 3 conditions, and so on. Thus, users can choose to fill in any possible combinations/number of inputs: minimum 1 and maximum 7. The conditions will only be set when the input field is filled. (Hope you guys understand where I am coming from hahaha)

Thus, I would like to ask, how do I go about approch to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryarray = array();

if(isset($_POST['field1'])&&strlen($_POST['field1']) > 0) array_push($queryarray,'column 1 = "'.$_POST['field1'].'"') ;
.
.
.
V
if(isset($_POST['field7'])&&strlen($_POST['field7'])>0) array_push($queryarray,'column 7 = "'.$_POST['field7'].'"') ;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE'.implode(' AND ', $queryarray);
```

I think this is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

```
As My understanding
HTML Form
<form action="#" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2">Search Field 1 </label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Field 1" name="Field[][Field_one]">
      </div>

      <label class="col-md-2">Search Field 2</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Field 2" name="Field[][Field_two]">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2">Search Field 3</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Field 1" name="Field[][Field_three]">
      </div>

      <label class="col-md-2">Search Field 4</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Field 4" name="Field[][Field_four]">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2">Search Field 5</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Field 5" name="Field[][Field_five]">
      </div>

      <label class="col-md-2">Search Field 6</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Field 6" name="Field[][Field_six]">
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2">Search Field 7</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Field 7" name="Field[][Field_seven]">
      </div>

    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2">Search</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>

   PHP Script:
if( isset( $_POST['Field'] ) ){
$levels = $_POST['Field'];  
    foreach($levels as $level ){
        if( isset($level['Field_one']) && strlen($level['Field_one']) > 0 ){
            $Field_one = $level['Field_one'] ;
        }
        if( isset($level['Field_two']) && strlen($level['Field_two']) > 0 ){
            $Field_two = $level['Field_two'];
        }
        if( isset($level['Field_three']) && strlen ($level['Field_three']) > 0 ){
            $Field_three = $level['Field_three'];
        }
        if( isset($level['Field_four']) && strlen($level['Field_four']) > 0 ){
            $Field_four = $level['Field_four'];
        }
        if( isset($level['Field_five']) && strlen($level['Field_five']) > 0 ){
            $Field_five = $level['Field_five'];
        }
        if( isset($level['Field_six']) && strlen($level['Field_six']) > 0 ){ 
            $Field_six = $level['Field_six'];
        }
        if( isset($level['Field_seven']) && strlen($level['Field_seven']) > 0 ){
            $Field_seven = $level['Field_seven'];
        }

    }// end foreach
}// end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply solution you can try the following.. it might help

```
//get all the request params
$request = $_POST;
$query_data = array();

//check for the each filter set or not 
if(isset($_POST['field1'] && $_POST['field1']!="" )){
    $query_data['column1'] = $_POST['field1'];
}
.
.
.
.
if(isset($_POST['field7']) && $_POST['field7']!=""){
    $query_data['column7'] = $_POST['field7'];
}

$where_condition = " where ";
foreach ($query_data as $key => $value ){
    $where_condition .= "$key='$value' AND ";
}
$where_condition .= " 1=1 "

$sql = "select * from table1  ".$where_condition;
```